# Ionic 2 - Nav undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to add navigation to the `app.component.ts` file in my Ionic 2 application. For some reason I'm receiving an error that `nav` is not defined.

Adding the `NavController` is no options either, since it'll say that there's no provider for `NavController`.

The error(s) I'm receiving are:

> Native: tried calling Facebook.browserInit, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator main.js (416,9)
>   Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. main.js (3511,5)
>   Native: tried calling NativeStorage.getItem, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator main.js (416,9)
>   Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator main.js (416,9)
>   EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise):
>   TypeError: Unable to get property 'nav' of undefined or null reference   TypeError: Unable to get property 'nav' of undefined or null reference
>       at Anonymous function (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/main.js:125439:17)
>       at t.prototype.invoke (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9569)
>      at onInvoke (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/main.js:38701:21)
>       at t.prototype.invoke (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9569)
>      at e.prototype.run (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:6993)
>      at Anonymous function (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4652)
>       at t.prototype.invokeTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10175)
>       at onInvokeTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/main.js:38692:21)
>       at t.prototype.invokeTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10175)
>       at e.prototype.runTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7611)
>     at i (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3700)
>       at invoke (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:11431)
>    main.js (78327,9)
>   ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: main.js (78332,13)
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>   TypeError: Unable to get property 'nav' of undefined or null reference
>   TypeError: Unable to get property 'nav' of undefined or null reference at Anonymous function (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/main.js:125439:17)
>     at t.prototype.invoke (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9569)
>       at onInvoke (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/main.js:38701:21)
>       at t.prototype.invoke (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9569)
>      at e.prototype.run (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:6993)
>      at Anonymous function (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4652)
>       at t.prototype.invokeTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10175)
>       at onInvokeTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/main.js:38692:21)
>       at t.prototype.invokeTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10175)
>       at e.prototype.runTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7611)
>     at i (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3700)
>       at invoke (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:11431)
>       at v (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4856)
>       at s (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4283)
>       at Anonymous function (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4690)
>       at t.prototype.invokeTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10175)
>       at onInvokeTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/main.js:38692:21)
>       at t.prototype.invokeTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10175)
>       at e.prototype.runTask (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7611)
>     at i (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3700)
>       at invoke (http:‍//localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:11431)
>    main.js (78333,13)

**The code I'm using:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen, NativeStorage, Facebook } from 'ionic-native';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage = LoginPage;

  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.InitliazeApp();
  }

  InitliazeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

      NativeStorage.getItem('user')
        .then(function (data) {
          this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
          Splashscreen.hide();
        }, function (error) {
          this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
          Splashscreen.hide();
        });

      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: add provider in ngModules

Comment: @varunaaruru I'm using Angular2 in my project, any idea where I should be adding this? By adding the NavController in my `app.module.ts` I'm receiving a lot of errors, so this probably isn't it..

Comment: can you show the html side?

Comment: Add nav html here and is this the browser error you have added because it seems cordova is not install..

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic2 you usually add navigation by adding NavController to the constructor. it is then injected using dependency injection.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController)
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the following in app.component.ts

> import { Nav, NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

Add the following code in constructor

> constructor(public navCtrl: NavController)

Comment: Please add also the main points of your solution instead of just code.

Comment: these are the main lines which need to be edited in the given code above @pirho

Comment: You can share your code.. what exactly you  are looking for